# Google Wallet pre-authorization on Android

Tags: android, android-pay

I'm trying to implement pre-authorization for google wallet purchases for an android application.  Google has [a page describing this feature](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/preauth), but the instructions stop after obtaining a api client ID; no code samples on how to initiate the request.

The API has [references to checking the status](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/Wallet.html#checkForPreAuthorization%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20int%29) of pre-authorization, but again nothing about how to request it.

Can anyone point me to a code sample or api call I'm missing?

Comment: This is still the case 5 months later. Does anyone have any resources for the pre-authorization check implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to make sure that the the developer console credentials contain the same credentials as your production+staging fingerprint.

There's no other work to do on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `checkForPreAuthorization` API to check if user pre-authorized for all future purchases

```
Wallet.Payments.checkForPreAuthorization(mGoogleApiClient, REQUEST_CODE);
```

REQUEST_CODE - will be passed back in onActivityResult where you can retrieve the result via EXTRA_IS_USER_PREAUTHORIZED.

Check this : https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/Payments.html#checkForPreAuthorization(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20int)

Comment: It was deprecated. Any alternatives?